# How to count total usages

Tags: sql, join, count

I have two tables (simplified):

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        code                             |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| code_id     | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| campaign_id | int          | FOREIGN KEY campaign       |
| code        | varchar(12)  |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        code_usages                      |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| code_usg_id | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| code_id     | int          | FOREIGN KEY code           |
| used_at     | DateTime     |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

*One **campaign** can have many codes, and one code can be used many times*. How can I count total codes and used codes (total count of all code usages for this **campaign_id**) grouped by campaign_id?

Example result:

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| campaign_id | used_times   |   total_codes   |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1           | 44           | 1               |
| 2           | 1            | 3               |
| 3           | 33           | 4               |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do, you group over campaigns and find count of all usages in the group (i.e. count all ID of usages) and count number of unique codes in the group

```
SELECT campaign_id, COUNT(code_usg_id) AS used_times, COUNT(DISTINCT c.code_id) AS total_codes   
FROM code c 
LEFT JOIN code_usages u
ON c.code_id = u.code_id   
GROUP BY campaign_id
```